# cmake swig miniconda3/ananconda3 error

Tags: python, macos, cmake, anaconda, swig

I believe there is an issue with the CMake SWIG module. I've provided a minimal working example to prove this.

https://github.com/kdheepak/mwe-mac-cmake-swig-miniconda3-error

This causes a `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` error with Python3 using Miniconda3 but no error if I use Miniconda2. This is the same if I use Anaconda3/Anaconda2 or if I use any environment. I believe the linking that is done by CMake is broken for some reason. I'm able to build the extension successfully using `setup.py`.

Can someone offer any suggestions here?

Comment: should be a bugreport to CMake.  don't think SO is the right place to post bugs.

Comment: As usr1234567 said, Stack Overflow is not bug-reporting site. If you think the problem could be in your code, you need to provide that code in the question post itself, not as an off-site project. This is a usual rule of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That indeed makes sense. I initially tried to post on https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues but that does not seem open to the public to post an issue.

Comment: It turns out you have to sign up on their gitlab website to post an issue. I just did that. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17664

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with CMake. I have reported it on the CMake bug tracker  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17664.